Can't make a new line in slim template
My code is the below.
mails_preview.rb

summaries = ["test\ntest\ntest\ntest", "test\ntest\ntest\ntest"]
ClientsMailer.test(summaries)

clients_mailer.rb

class ClientsMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def test(summaries)
    @summaries = summaries

    mail(
      to: "test@test.com,
      subject: "test",
    )
  end
end

test.slim

= @summaries.map { |summary| summary }.join("\n")

Output is here


test test test test test test test test


\n doesn't work for making a new line.

I can't understand why.

Do you have any ideas?

I lacked .html_safe.

fixed code is the below.
test.slim

= @summaries.map { |summary| summary }.join("\n").html_safe


Make sure that you can trust the source of @summaries when using html_safe. You should – for security reasons – not use html_safe with text that were provided by users.

Thank you for your attention. summaries is not from users.
